# PHP Code Not Working when CloudFlare is running?

Tags: php, jquery, cloudflare, jcrop

The code below used to work flawlessly to crop an image that was already uploaded (via JQuery JCrop). As soon as I configured CloudFlare, it fails to crop the image (but still uploads successfully). Any ideas on how to fix this?

My current PHP Version is 7.0, and I am using DigitalOcean as my web host.

```
<?php

require_once('auth.php');
require_once('connection.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
 $targ_w = 150;
 $targ_h = 200;


 $src = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd,$_POST['src']);

 $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

 $img = resize_image($src, $_POST['imgWidth'], $_POST['imgHeight']);

 imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],150,200,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

 imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,90);


 //Cropping complete, move to next page

 //header("location: profileSetup.php");



 exit; 
 }


function isPNG($file){
    return preg_match('/'.quotemeta('PNG').'/i', file_get_contents($file));
}



function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }



    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    if(exif_imagetype($file) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG){
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    }
    else{
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    }



    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue for myself. There was nothing wrong with the PHP code. CloudFlare was caching the images, and all I had to do was add a random integer into the new image name to prevent this from occurring!